# How to execute a junit testcase at runtime?

Tags: junit

I want to execute a junit testcase inside another java program.. Let's say

```
class XYZ extends TestCase{
    public void test1(){}
    public void test2(){}
    public void test3(){}
}
```

Like the way I run this unit test on eclipse, I want to be able to execute this at run time..I need to know the number of tests passed and failed.. I tried the typical java way of doing this by creating an object of this testcase class and invoking each function one by one but somehow I felt it is ineffective to do so.. Also, it does execute the tests but doesn't tell me anything about the statistics about tests passed and failed..

So how can I execute all this tests at run time within another java program, mimicking what eclipse does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JunitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) class to execute tests programmatically. This will return a [Result](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Result.html) which you will have to evaluate for yourself.

> Once you have tests, you'll want to run them. JUnit provides tools to
>   define the suite to be run and to display its results. To run tests
>   and see the results on the console, run this from a Java program:
>
> ```
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(TestClass1.class, ...);
> ```