# Running JUnit test classes at runtime

Tags: java, junit

Is it possible to run TestX.class at runtime and get a result in JUnit 5?

I found an [old post that explains how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531984/7227475) but can't find that class in JUnit5 and therefore can't seem to run test classes during runtime.

Example: I have compiled a TestX.class (using JavaCompiler API) - see the code below:

```
 @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class StringUtilsTestUnit5 {

  @Test
  public void testConvertToDoubleOK() {
    // Test case with the age is a numeric string
    String age = "1990";
    Double expAge = Double.valueOf(age);
    Double actual = StringUtils.convertToDouble(age);

    assertAll("Do many assertions.", () -> {
      assertNotNull(actual);
      assertEquals(expAge, actual);
    });
    }
```

Running the code results in a message stating that all the tests have passed in X time and so on.

Is it possible to execute the tests (and get results) as they were executed in earlier JUnit versions?

Comment: certainly unclear what you are trying to ask. Be more specific please.

Comment: Well, I posted SO link to exactly what I want to do. Run test class at runtime and receive results from those tests at runtime.

Comment: Guess what? Someone here already looked for JUnitCore.runClasses in JUnit5, and here's what they got: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111501/whats-the-equivalent-of-org-junit-runner-junitcore-runclasses-in-junit-5